# align minus sign and equal sign

Tags: align

When using align, the `=` sign and the `-`sign don't get properly aligned. How can I get these two to be properly aligned?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&-& &\sum_{n=0}& &\frac{a}{b}& \\
&=& &\sum_{n=0}& &\frac{a}{b}&
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `&{}-{}& &\sum_{n=0}& &\frac{a}{b}&` (the addition of empty groups `{}` before/after the `-`) will adjust the first line properly

Comment: Alternately, in the 2nd line, enclose the `=` in a group, as in `&{=}& &\sum_{n=0}& &\frac{a}{b}&`

Comment: Can you please show a real world example? I'm not sure why you'd want such an alignment

Comment: You're not really trying to get this particular code published, do you? Please provide a real example.

Comment: How about `\mathrel{-}`, which changes the spacing around `-` to match that of `=`.